# Can I recover data from a drive that was removed from a Btrfs filesystem?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, btrfs

I have recently moved my a Btrfs filesystem from a 4TB HDDto a 500GB SSD. This had me delete some old backups that I deemed no longer needed, since I didn't access them in a year or more, adding the SSD to the filesystem (`btrfs dev add /dev/SDD /mount/point`) and then removing the HDD from it, effectively migrating the Btrfs filesystem to another drive.

Ironically, the very next day I have been looking for some files that might probably be in that old backup that I have just deleted.

I figure that the files might still be on the 4TB HDD as Btrfs had no reason to wipe the data.

I have tried running `btrfs restore` on the device, but it reports that it can't find any Btrfs superblocks there.

I have tried `testdisk` but the filesystem was made on a raw device, not a partition. plus I don't know what good that do anyway.

Is there a way to recover files from a device that was part of a Btrfs filesystem but was removed from it?

PS:

I've since found the files I've been looking for elsewhere, but this is still something I'd want to know.